# Having Trouble Applying HTTPS to Proper Site Areas

Tags: .htaccess, https

New to developing.  I am attempting to apply HTTPS to certain pages of my site, while others remain unsecure.  I have experimented with my .htaccess file but remain stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Right now the HTTPS is not activated when you arrive at the Index page at the beginning of your visit.  It is activated as soon as you navigate away from the Index page and then remains active for the remainder of your visit.  The exceptions to the rule are Best Practices Blog (Wordpress) and Store (Zen Cart), which were uploaded whole and are functioning properly.

Without upsetting Zen Cart or Wordpress, I want to apply HTTPS to the Pay_My_Bill_Online section while Index, About_Us, Contact_Us and Links remain unsecure.  Right now the site files are all in the root directory (except Blog and Store which are in folders), and if possible I would prefer to not segregate each page into a folder at this point.

Note: Pay_My_Bill_Online content is not in final form.  Once it is done the Paypal button will be gone and the form at bottom will be restyled for payment information input.

Site address:  http://www.mconchicago.com

My current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} html 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mconchicago.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: What are the urls for those sections? What is working with you current htaccess and what is not?

Comment: www.mconchicago.com/index.html  www.mconchicago.com/About_Us.html  www.mconchicago/Contact_Us.html  www.mconchicago.com/Pay_My_Bill_Online.html  www.mconchicago.com/blog, www.mconchicago.com/store www.mconchicago.com/Links.html                Right now HTTPS is being applied to the whole site.  I need to only apply it to certain pages.

Answer (score 0):

Just to bring my above question to a useful conclusion:

I did break down and move the Pay_My_Bill_Online files into their own folder.  I put the above .htaccess file into the new folder and removed it from the main site directory.  It is now applying properly in IE9, Firefox Chrome and Safari.  It is not applying itself properly in Opera.  As I have read reports quoting Opera being used for between 2-5% of searches this is something  I plan to fix.  I will report back once I get to the bottom of this final hiccup.  Of course, if anyone has comments in the meantime I would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately decided to remove Pay_My_Bill_Online.  I have a feeling that security knowledge above basic HTTPS is needed to have such a feature.  Upon reflection having a form which takes credit card information seems to involve significant potential liability.  Looking around various blogs suggested that not many people have gone down the same road.  So I will leave the idea alone for the moment, and find a way to run all transactions through the Store section.  I don't think this ideal for billable work.  But it seems most prudent to leave financial transactions in the hands of people who specialize (merchant providers/Paypal).  I may in the future apply the HTTPS to the Contact_Us form.  But simple name, address and email content make this a lower priority concern.